# Trying to install Ubuntu Server as RAID 1, leads to "ValueError: Failed to find storage volume"

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, raid, 21.04

I have 2 M.2 NVMe disks on a server that I'd like to setup as a RAID 1 for an Ubuntu Server installation. I was following these two guides ([first](https://gist.github.com/fevangelou/2f7aa0d9b5cb42d783302727665bf80a) and [second](https://alexskra.com/blog/ubuntu-20-04-with-software-raid1-and-uefi/)) but will explain the steps I did and the resulting error.

A few things to note: These drives are working - both have held operating systems and functioned perfectly. I also first attempted the installation with Ubuntu Server 21.04. After it failed there, I moved to Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 and had the exact same issue.

---

I booted the installer, chose default configurations all the way up to the "Use entire disk or custom?" section. From there I chose "custom" installation and set up a simple layout:

1. Both disks were formatted.
2. Both disks marked as bootable drives.
3. I added 1 unformatted partition to the both disks that used the entire disk space.
4. I created a RAID group, using those two unformatted partitions as `/dev/md0`
5. I formatted `/dev/md0` as `ext4` and mounted it to `/`
6. I hit `Done` and let the installation proceed.
7. After about 5-10 minutes, it fails with the error: `ValueError: Failed to find storage volume id='disk-nvme1n1'`

You can [watch my video showing the error log here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/7SAm964rzkCnBjdX7). Around 1:28 is where I start focusing on the error output.

---

Extra information that could be relevant?

- M.2 Drives are [XPG GAMMIX S50 Lite 2TB.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08HW4WR7C)
- Motherboard is [Asus ROG Zenith II Extreme Alpha](https://rog.asus.com/us/motherboards/rog-zenith/rog-zenith-ii-extreme-alpha-model/)
- Processor is [AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3970x](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-threadripper-3970x)

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat solved?

My "solution" was to only create a partition at `/` that was 10GB instead of 1.86TB and that somehow let the installer make it all the way through (did the operation time out before? Had the drive become overworked and just quit? I'm unsure) I plan on expanding the storage now while I'm booted into the machine.

At the same time I also did this so unsure if it's part of the solution but sharing just in case: While booting the Ubuntu server installer, in the grub boot menu, I chose "Boot and Install with the HWE kernel".

[image: Boot and Install with the HWE kernel]

I hope that helps anyone who runs into the same issue.